# c++ class used so that when instantiated produces a compile error

Tags: c++

As I asked and had been answered in a previous question if it is possible to create a class conditionally the code bellow followed. When the condition is no more acceptable it should be possible to instantiate a class that generates a compile error.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits> // for std::conditional

using namespace std;

template <size_t N> 
  using Float_4=conditional< 80<N && N<=128, _Float128,bool>::type;
template <size_t N> 
  using Float_3=conditional< 64<N && N<= 80,__float80 ,Float_4<N>>::type;
template <size_t N> 
  using Float_2=conditional< 32<N && N<= 64, _Float64 ,Float_3<N>>::type;
template <size_t N> 
  using Float_1=conditional< 16<N && N<= 32, _Float32 ,Float_2<N>>::type;
template <size_t N> 
  using Float_0=conditional<  0<N && N<= 16, _Float16 ,Float_1<N>>::type;

typedef Float_0<80> Float;
```

In the first case when all conditions do not meet, I would like to put instead of "bool" a class "UnexistentClass" in order to generate a compile error when it is the case.

Is that possible somehow ?

Comment: Re: "Instantiate a class" -- you can instantiate a **template**; if it's a class template, instantiating it creates a class. You cannot instantiate a class. It already exists. The code in the question isn't dealing in any way with classes; it's simply creating creating typedefs for non-standard scalar types.

Comment: George, since this question is still open, did you ever get any of the answers to work so that you get a compilation error if you try to use 0 or more than 128 bits? If not, please ask for clarification.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes I used it just now, and your solution indeed works, albeit, to be honest I do not really understand the syntax used. Regarding the first example, you define a struct named Floater and you set "using type=_Float16;" that is not known to me as meaning or syntax!

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis _"our solution indeed works"_ - Great! _"you define a struct"_ - `using` is the "new" way of doing `typedef`s. Instead of `using type = _Float16;` you could write `typedef _Float16 type;` The result in my example is that only the specializations of the `Floater` class template has `type` defined - which means that if the `conditional_t`s end up at the end (`Floater<N>`) it'll result in a compilation error because we'll then be doing `typename Floater<N>::type` - but there is no `type` in `Floater<N>` (except in the specializations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a helper, here called `Floater`, that defines a `type` in specializations and use the primary template (which is lacking `type`) as a fallback to generate a compilation error.

Example:

```cpp
template<size_t> struct Floater {}; // no "type" in the primary template
// specializations:
template<> struct Floater<16> { using type = _Float16; };
template<> struct Floater<32> { using type = _Float32; };
template<> struct Floater<64> { using type = _Float64; };
template<> struct Floater<80> { using type = __float80; };
template<> struct Floater<128> { using type = _Float128; };
```

Then select the `Floater` using `std::conditional`:

```cpp
template <size_t N = 80>
using Float =
    typename std::conditional_t<0 < N && N <= 16, Floater<16>,
             std::conditional_t<16 < N && N <= 32, Floater<32>,
             std::conditional_t<32 < N && N <= 64, Floater<64>,
             std::conditional_t<64 < N && N <= 80, Floater<80>,
             std::conditional_t<80 < N && N <= 128, Floater<128>,
                                                    Floater<N>>>>>>::type;
```

An alternative, using the same template for `Floater`, without using `std::conditional` could look like this:

```cpp
template <size_t N = 80>
using Float = typename Floater<(0 < N && N <= 16)   * 16 +
                               (16 < N && N <= 32)  * 32 +
                               (32 < N && N <= 64)  * 64 +
                               (64 < N && N <= 80)  * 80 +
                               (80 < N && N <= 128) * 128>::type;
```

A variant of the second version above requires a slight change of the `Floater` specializations, but makes the `Float` helper type easier to define:

```cpp
// specializations:
template<> struct Floater<1> { using type = _Float16; };
template<> struct Floater<2> { using type = _Float32; };
template<> struct Floater<3> { using type = _Float64; };
template<> struct Floater<4> { using type = __float80; };
template<> struct Floater<5> { using type = _Float128; };

template <size_t N = 80>
using Float = typename Floater<(N > 0) + (N > 16) + (N > 32) + (N > 64) +
                               (N > 80) + (N > 128)>::type;
```

In all versions, this will hold:

```cpp
int main() {
    Float<> x;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), __float80>);

    // Float<0> a;   // error
    // Float<129> b; // error
}
```

Comment: Your answer created the question "what is the difference between conditional and conditional_t . If you may help there too ...

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis Ah, ok, it is just a helper type, defined as `template<bool B, class T, class F> using conditional_t = typename conditional<B,T,F>::type;`

Comment: But in the code above you already use a prefix "typename" and a suffix "::type", so how does it works ? I am confused ... typename std::conditional_t<0 < N && N <= 16, Floater<16>, std::conditional_t<16 < N && N <= 32, Floater<32>,
             std::conditional_t<32 < N && N <= 64, Floater<64>,
             std::conditional_t<64 < N && N <= 80, Floater<80>,
             std::conditional_t<80 < N && N <= 128, Floater<128>,
                                                    Floater<N>>>>>>::type;

Comment: Yes, `conditional_t` selects the appropriate `Floater` and the `Float` helper type is defined to similarly do `template<size_t N> using Float = typename Floater<(deduced x from N)>::type`. Compare with the last two implementations where that is a lot clearer. If we had used `std::conditional` (without `_t`) then it would have ended `>::type>::type`.

Comment: So the code you wrote should miss the starting typedef and final ::type, I compiled it as that and it works, could you please clarify ?

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but the code as presented in the answer compiles and works without changes.

Comment: Based on your indications I settled on the bellow code:

template <size_t N> 
using FloatX =  
 conditional_t<  0<N && N<= 16, _Float16,
 conditional_t< 16<N && N<= 32, _Float32,
 conditional_t< 32<N && N<= 64, _Float64,
 conditional_t< 64<N && N<= 80, __float80,
 conditional_t< 80<N && N<=128, _Float128,
 nullptr_t
>>>>>;

typedef FloatX<18> Float;

I don't exactly understand why there is a typedef and ::type in your code compared to mine.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis There's no `FloatX` in my answer. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/67Wbsq8vT). Also, when using [what you settled for](https://godbolt.org/z/1975v9e79), you haven't really accomplished your goal of generating a compilation error for `FloatX<0>` and `FloatX<129>` (or above).

Answer (score 1):

If you use a helper function for determining the type via `if constexpr`, you can add a `static_assert` checking the maximum for the number of bits:

```
template<unsigned bits>
auto FloatVal()
{
    static_assert(bits <= 128, "no more than 128 bits are allowed");

    if constexpr (bits <= 16)
    {
        return _Float16{};
    }
    else if constexpr (bits <= 32)
    {
        return _Float32{};
    }
    else if constexpr (bits <= 64)
    {
        return _Float64{};
    }
    else if constexpr (bits <= 80)
    {
        return _Float80{};
    }
    else
    {
        return _Float128{};
    }
}

template<unsigned bits>
using FloatType = decltype(FloatVal<bits>());
```

```
using X = FloatType<128>; // OK
using Y = FloatType<129>; // Error
```