# what is the difference between std::conditional and std::conditional_t c++

Tags: c++, type-traits

I cannot find in c++ the difference between `std::conditional< >::type` and `std::conditional_t< >` .

When I compile

```
 using A = typename conditional< true, int, char>::type;                     
 using B = typename conditional_t< true, int, char>::type;
```

an error: expected nested-name-specifier gets out.
I was unable to use `conditional` and nest, while `conditional_t` seems to nest.

Comment: `std::conditional::type` and `std::conditional_t` are  [the same thing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional). Don't use `::type` with `std::conditional_t`; it's already been done.

Comment: If I read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional#helper_types) right, `std::conditional<>` and `std::conditional_t<>` should be the same, except that the version with the `_t` does not need a `::type` at the end.

Comment: TL;DR: alias templates like `std::conditional_t` weren't possible before C++11, so you had to manually access member aliases of a template as `std::conditional<...>::type`. Now that alias templates are a thing, you can use them to save some verbosity and complexity. There should be a duplicate stating as much somewhere...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are C++11 type traits not alias templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498444/why-are-c11-type-traits-not-alias-templates). The [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9501282/11082165) discusses why type traits didn't use alias templates from the start

Comment: #include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

using F = typename conditional< true, int, char>::type;                     
using G = typename conditional_t< true, int, char>;                     
using H = typename conditional_t< true, int, char>::type;                     
                       
int main(){
    F f=658979;
    G g=4546;
    H h=654;
    return 0;
}
                                                              
 DOES NOT COMPILE for both cases of conditional_t. It says something about nested ...

Comment: code in comments is not readable. If you actually wanted to ask a different question about different code you can open a new question

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis I understand [where this question is coming from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76907233/7582247) and I tried to answer it in the comment section. What I did was `using X = typename conditional_t<Condition, A, B>::type;` - which requires `A` and `B` to have a `type` defined. `X` will therefore be `typename A::type` or `typename B::type`. If `type` is missing from the selected type (`A` or `B`) there will be a compilation error - as you requested in that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::conditional_t` is just a helper alias. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
template< bool B, class T, class F >
using conditional_t = typename conditional<B,T,F>::type;
```

On the same link you can also find the statement:

> The behavior of a program that adds specializations for `std::conditional` is undefined.

The same is not true for type traits you write or that come with libraries. And then the crux is that the fact that `some_trait::type` is a type is only a convention. Nothing in the language forbids you to specialize `some_trait` such that `type` is a static member of type `int` whose value is `42`.

And thats why you need to disambiguate the member alias `type` via `typename` (see [When is the "typename" keyword necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923369/when-is-the-typename-keyword-necessary)). `std::conditional_t` on the other hand is a type alias. It can only be a type. Its a helper that makes the use of the trait more convenient.

`std::conditional_t` (usually) has no member alias `type`. It is an alias for the member alias `type` of `std::conditional`.

Comment: The nesting error was caused from the superfluous typename ::type

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis ah now I remember that the error message says something along the line of "no nested ...". Thats why code and error message should be in the question when the question is about broken code. Anyhow, this question is not about the code, its just the "nest" you mention that is a little confusing

Answer (score 4):

Due to a design flaw in C++ templates, it turns out that creating a helper alias for type-functions is useful.

So `std::conditional<bool, A, B>` is a type-function template.  Its `::type` is either `A` or `B`.

`std::conditional_t<bool, A, B>` is an helper alias that evaluates to `std::conditional<bool, A, B>::type`.  In most contexts, doing `::type` on `std::conditional` requires you disambiguate with a `typename` prefix so the compiler knows that `::type` is a type and not a value - but `std::conditional_t` does this for you, as it is syntactically known to be a type without a `typename`.

In the C++ `std` library, almost all (and maybe all) templates with a `::type` member now come with a helper `_t` template that does this, which makes a bunch of use nicer.

Comment: "design flaw" ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yes, the need for disambiguators in template code is a design flaw of C++.  I get why it happened; still, it was a design flaw.  Nobody would design a language de novo and include it.

Comment: in hindsight yes. Afaik nobody was really aware of what templates will become when they started as generic containers. I was refering to the typo ;)